# UNMutableNotificationContent with custom object in userinfo

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, userinfo, nssecurecoding

I want to use a cutom object in userinfo of a UNMutableNotificationContent but it doesn’t work.
When I put a custom object in userinfo, notification is not fired.

With this code, a notification is fired:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "title"
content.body = "body"
content.categoryIdentifier = "alarmNotificationCategory"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
content.userInfo = ["myKey": "myValue"] as [String : Any]


let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "alarmNotification", content: content, trigger: nil)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    if error != nil {
        print(error!)
    }
}
```

With the following, no error but notification is not fired:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "title"
content.body = "body"
content.categoryIdentifier = "alarmNotificationCategory"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
content.userInfo = ["myKey": TestClass(progress: 2)] as [String : Any]


let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "alarmNotification", content: content, trigger: nil)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    if error != nil {
        print(error!)
    }
}
```

TestClass is the custom class, here is the definition:

```
class TestClass: NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
    public var progress: Float = 0

    required override public init() {
        super.init()
    }

    public init(progress: Float) {
        self.progress = progress
    }

    public required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
        progress = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "progress") as! Float
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(progress, forKey: "progress")
    }

    public static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool {
        get {
            return true
        }
    }

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: I have the same problem, for example i want to pass an UIImage in userInfo and not notification is not fired at all. It seems that you can pass only primitive types (Int, String, floats etc).

Answer (score 8):

You object should be Property List

> The keys in this dictionary must be property-list types—that is, they
>   must be types that can be serialized into the property-list format.
>   For information about property-list types, see Property List
>   Programming Guide.

you can convert your object to NSData (archive it using NSArchiver)